# WiFi Network Goes Offline Every Few Minutes

Tags: release-freya

In my previous operating system (Windows 10), there were occasional issues with the WiFi needing to reconnect; but after switching to Elementary, Web pages become unresponsive and I have to keep disconnecting and reconnecting every few minutes just to be able to surf the Web. It is possible to live with, but it's certainly annoying.

Output of `sudo lshw -C network` command:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 90:2b:34:a1:01:b4
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:40 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d0904000-d0904fff memory:d0900000-d0903fff
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of "sudo lshw -C network"  to know your wifi driver.

Answer (score 1):

Install third party Realtek wifi drivers. Follow this link check out right side text.
 https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7#TOC-The-rtlwifi_new-driver-from-lwfinger
And next time you buy computer make sure it's not shipped with Realtek wifi chipset at least I won't be buying one.

Comment: Thank you! My WiFi connection has been much more stable and snappy since following the appropriate steps at the above URL.

Comment: Mark as answer.